# RavenDB 4 - change timestamp of revision

Tags: nhibernate, ravendb, data-migration, nhibernate-envers, ravendb4

I'm planning to move from SAP SQLAnywhere + NHibernate + Envers to RavenDB4.

I'm doing some migration and performance tests. At this time, I'm looking for an way to migrate Envers Audit to Raven revision.

What I'm trying:

1. Read source audit record.
2. Insert it on RavenDB.
3. Patch it, for every record on audit.

Everything is working fine, but I need to change raven revision timestamp from migration point to saved Envers timestamp.
Any clue to do that or perhaps a better way to do this migration?

I want to avoid create another collection to legacy data or adding original timestamp as metadata.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify the revision data. This is done as part of the frozen nature of revisions.

Comment: You can export and import the data, that would create a new item, not an existing one